# Changing Google Play Developer Account from Individual to Organization After Linking Payment Profile

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I'm currently facing a challenge with my Google Play developer account and am looking for practical solutions. I have a developer account set up as an organization, for which I've paid the $25 registration fee. However, I mistakenly set up the associated payments profile as an 'individual' instead of an 'organization'.

Upon reaching out to Google support, I was informed that a linked Play Console and payments profile can't be unlinked or altered. Their suggested solution is to create a new developer account, pay another registration fee, and transfer any existing apps to this new account.

Given the impracticality of closing my current developer account, transferring apps, and recreating a new account just for this issue, I am seeking alternative solutions. Here are my specific questions:

1. Is there any known workaround or alternative method within Google's policy framework that would allow for changing the payment profile type from individual to organization without needing to create a new developer account?
2. Has anyone successfully addressed a similar issue without having to go through the process of account recreation and app transfer?
3. Are there any potential risks or limitations I should be aware of if I continue operating with the payment profile set as 'individual' for an organization's developer account?
4. What practical steps can I take to minimize any negative impact this situation may have on my business operations or app development process?

Any advice or shared experiences from those who have navigated similar issues or have a deep understanding of Google Play policies would be extremely valuable.

Comment: Welcome! This does not look like a programming question. But I can not tell you where on SO to place it better.